# Definitions of nice recursive analogues of cofinality?

Tags: set-theory, computability, ordinals

The cofinality of an ordinal is the minimal order type of a cofinal subset of that ordinal. In the study of admissible ordinals, some concepts that mimic the idea of cofinality appear. One common example is the $\Sigma_1$-cofinality of an ordinal $\alpha$, whose definition is the same as the cofinality of $\alpha$ except instead of considering all $\alpha$-unbounded subsets we only consider those that are also ranges of $\alpha$-recursive functions. (We will call these $\alpha$-recursive sets.)

If we use this definition for "recursive" or "effective" cofinality, we get some results that scale nicely: like how regular ordinals are those where $\alpha=\textrm{cof}(\alpha)$, the "recursively regular" (i.e. admissible) ordinals are those where $\alpha=\Sigma_1\textrm{-cof}(\alpha)$. However, because according to Sacks's [*Higher Recursion Theory*](https://projecteuclid.org/ebook/Download?urlId=pl%2F1235422639&isFullBook=False) there exists a $\omega_1^{CK}$-recursive injection from $\omega_1^{CK}$ into $\omega$, from it we can construct a $\omega_1^{CK}\cdot 2$-recursive subset of $\omega_1^{CK}\cdot 2$ with order type $\omega$. So $\Sigma_1\textrm{-cof}(\omega_1^{CK}\cdot 2)=\omega$. This isn't what we want, since $\textrm{cof}(\omega_1\cdot 2)=\omega_1$. So $\Sigma_1$-cofinality, while okay in some cases, isn't what we want for a good concept of effective cofinality.

Are there any known concepts of "effective cofinality" that the behavior of $\textrm{cof}$ scales nicely to? I've asked two other people and neither was aware of one that didn't have this unwanted behavior in particular.

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually think that the situation you're describing really is a problem.

Remember that $\Sigma_1$ definability (along with any notion of effectivity, really) is **relative to a domain**. Modifying [Sacks' notation](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Higher-Recursion-Theory/toc/pl/1235422631) a bit, it's not really that $$\sigma1\mathrm{cf}(\omega_1^{CK})\not=\sigma1\mathrm{cf}(\omega_1^{CK}\cdot 2),$$ but rather that $$\sigma1\mathrm{cf}^{\omega_1^{CK}}(\omega_1^{CK})\not=\sigma1\mathrm{cf}^{\omega_1^{CK}\cdot 2}(\omega_1^{CK}\cdot 2).$$ Here "$\sigma1\mathrm{cf}^\alpha(\beta)$" is the smallest ordinal with a $\Sigma_1$-over-$L_\alpha$ cofinal map into $\beta$, while "$\sigma1\mathrm{cf}(\beta)$" is $\sigma1\mathrm{cf}^\beta(\beta)$. For all limit $\alpha$ and all $\beta\cdot 2\le\alpha$ we clearly have $\sigma1\mathrm{cf}^\alpha(\beta)=\sigma1\mathrm{cf}(\beta\cdot2)$ as desired. Meanwhile, the discrepancy between $\sigma1\mathrm{cf}(\beta)$ and $\sigma1\mathrm{cf}(\beta\cdot 2)$ in general is due to the fact that $L_{\beta\cdot 2}$ is generally somewhat richer - if only in a pathological way! - than $L_{\beta}$.

The key insight that higher recursion theory has here is that we're usually not interested in some overarching notion of effective cofinality full stop, but rather in how deeply a single ordinal can "see" into itself. Change the ordinal, even in seemingly mild ways, and you change that capacity - so you should see (at least sometimes) corresponding changes in combinatorial invariants.

Comment: Thanks! As you mention it, it makes sense how $\newcommand{\cf}{\sigma1cf}\cf$ is relative to a domain - this reminds me of Jensen's work on projecta, which Devlin described as the "hard core" of an $L$-rank. However I'm working in the context of ordinal collapsing functions based on admissible ordinals, where a notion of cofinality matching that of uncountable cardinals would be helpful. E.g if we fixed some $\alpha$ beyond the function's range, $L_\alpha$ would be too complex, we would have $\cf^\alpha(\omega_1^{CK})=\cf^\alpha(\omega_1^{CK}2)=\omega$.How do we choose $\alpha$ to avoid this?

Comment: @C7X I'm not very familiar with proof theory to be honest, but I suspect that none of the $\sigma1\mathrm{cf}^\alpha$s as literally phrased above will quite do. I think it would help me (but might take a lot of work on your part) if you stated some precise axioms your effective cofinality function should satisfy, and/or what this desired function should itself be used for.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's my fault for posting a vague question. The main problem I'd run into with drafting these axioms is coming up with an extension of "recursive function" for ordinals that includes functions whose domain contains $\omega_1^{CK}$ but also doesn't include maps whose paradigm informally "arises from $L_{\omega_1^{CK}+1}$'s complexity", like the metarecursive $\omega_1^{CK}\to\omega$ injection. I feel like models of computation are my friend here, and also that right after defining this I will be able to extract a definition of effective cofinality from it.

Comment: @C7X Maybe look at notions like "safe recursive set functions" and similar (e.g. [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43864246))?

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.